# PNK exchange - What are the differences between these Schneider Electric stock symbols?

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, international-trading

Can someone help me understand the differences between all the stock symbols I found for Schneider Electric?

I found three:

- Schneider Electric S.E. (SU.PA) PAR
- Schneider Electric S.E. (SBGSF) PNK
- Schneider Electric S.E. (SBGSY) PNK

What does "PNK" mean? Why are there two symbols for the same company in this "PNK"?

Answer (score 3):

- Schneider Electric S.E. ([SU.PA](https://live.euronext.com/en/product/equities/FR0000121972-XPAR)) PAR - Schneider's listing on the Euronext Paris exchange.
- Schneider Electric S.E. ([SBGSF](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/SBGSF/overview)) PNK - This is an "F share" (the 5-letter ticker ends with "F"). US broker-dealers created this ticker to provide US investors with quotes of Schneider in US dollars instead of Euros. This represents US over-the-counter market quotes of Schneider's Euronext Paris  shares. More details about F shares: [FAQ on F Shares - OTC Markets](https://www.otcmarkets.com/files/FAQ-F-Shares.pdf)
- Schneider Electric S.E. ([SBGSY](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/SBGSY/overview)) PNK - This is an American Depositary Receipt (ADR), as evidenced by its 5-letter ticker that ends with "Y". This represents Schneider's unsponsored ADR traded on the US over-the-counter markets. If you're not familiar with ADRs, read: [American Depositary Receipt – ADR](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/adr.asp)

> What does "PNK" mean?

"PNK" is short for [Pink Sheets](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pinksheets.asp). This is the US over-the-counter (OTC) market for stocks I mentioned above. Beware of potential liquidity issues and extra brokerage fees when trading OTC securities.

Which should you choose? If you are able to buy securities listed on the Euronext Paris exchange, you should choose "SU.PA" over the others, because it is the official listing and has the highest liquidity.